# Generate JQuery code inside a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, increment

**UPDATE**
for JLRiche

html structure below (here is the structure for the entire div id=content_body_right):

```
    <div id="content_body_right">
        <p class="user_text">Tim Flanagan</p><p class="date_text">02-06-2013 @ 12:00PM</p>
                <p class="message_text">Playin Augusta today. What a beautiful course!</p>
                <div id="activity_image">
                    <img src="images/activities/1/actimg.jpg" width="435" />
                </div>
                <div id="tips">
                    <div id="tip_cap_left">
                        <a href="dashboard.php?captip=tipyourcap" title="Tip Your Cap" ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tip_cap_right">
                        <p class="tips_right">12 Tips of the Cap</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="comments_label">
                    4 Comments&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#" class="see_all" style="display:inline-block" title="See All Comments">see all</a>
                    <a href="#" class="collapse" style="display:none" title="Collapse Comments">collapse</a>
                </p>
                <div id="comment1">
                    <div id="comment_user_img">
                        <img src="images/defaultuserimg.jpg" width="30" height="30" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="comment_user">
                        <p class="user_text_comment">Tim Flanagan</p><p class="date_text_comment">02-06-2013 @ 12:00PM</p>
                        <p class="message_text_comment">Nice jealous of you bro.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment2" style="display:none; clear:both; margin:0px; overflow:auto">
                    <div id="comment2_sub">
                        <div id="comment_user_img">
                            <img src="images/defaultuserimg.jpg" width="30" height="30" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="comment_user">
                            <p class="user_text_comment">Tim Flanagan</p><p class="date_text_comment">02-06-2013 @ 12:00PM</p>
                            <p class="message_text_comment">Nice jealous of you bro.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="comment2_sub"> 
                        <div id="comment_user_img">
                            <img src="images/defaultuserimg.jpg" width="30" height="30" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="comment_user">
                            <p class="user_text_comment">Tim Flanagan</p><p class="date_text_comment">02-06-2013 @ 12:00PM</p>
                            <p class="message_text_comment">Nice jealous of you bro.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="comment2_sub">                  
                        <div id="comment_user_img">
                            <img src="images/defaultuserimg.jpg" width="30" height="30" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="comment_user">
                            <p class="user_text_comment">Tim Flanagan</p><p class="date_text_comment">02-06-2013 @ 12:00PM</p>
                            <p class="message_text_comment">Nice jealous of you bro.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Let me know if you need more structure, because there is alot above and below it. Hope this helps.
I really appreciate your help!

**END UPDATE**

Good Evening All,

I need to dynamically create X amount of jquery scripts foreach of the X amount of db results. X meaning the the number will vary. It is sort of a forum type thing where you see the original post with one reply showing and you would click see all or collapse all to view or collapse the rest. I am incrementing my html elements inside a foreach loop with the typical $i variable so I need to output jquery click functions for each as well.

The code I need PHP to create is below:

```
$jquery .= "$('#see_all$i').click(function () {
    $('#comment2_$i').slideDown('fast');
    $('#collapse$i').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('#see_all$i').css('display', 'none');
    return false;
});

$('#collapse$i').click(function () {
    $('#comment2_$i').slideUp('fast');
    $('#collapse$i').css('display', 'none');
    $('#see_all$i').css('display', 'inline-block');
    return false;
})";
```

Any help would and always will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you're doing it the wrong way round, make a class, put the index in a data-elid attribute (for example); in js bind the class to click event, retrive the id with `$(this).data("elid")`

Comment: Just put it in the scripts tag on top of the page and It would work for all the replies or where ever you want to use, not that much code for every reply. :/

Comment: if you ever find yourself making varying numbers or names part of a variable name, function, class, id, or any other kind of identifier, you should step back and consider if there's a more general way to solve your problem

Comment: @Eevee, I'll keep that in mind, I find myself doing this often, and usually find a way to get it done, probably the wrong way, but I feel great after figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

Generating multiple, slightly different copies of the same jQuery code is not a very good design, IMHO.  You should write your jQuery code in a way that it only needs to be in your page once, like:

```
$('.see_all').click(function(){
     var thisItem = $(this);
     thisItem.parent().find('.comment').slideDown('fast');
     thisItem.parent().find('.collapse').css('display','inline-block');
     thisItem.css('display','none');
     return false;
}); 

$('.collapse').click(function(){
     var thisItem = $(this);
     thisItem.parent().find('.comment').slideUp('fast');
     thisItem.css('display','none');
     thisItem.parent().find('.see_all').css('display','inline-block');
     return false;
})";
```

Of course, this would also involve adding `collapse`, `see_all`, and `comment` classes to the relevant HTML elements.

Comment: i would additionally avoid fiddling with CSS rules from JS manually; just add a class like `expanded` to the parent element, and have a rule like `.thread.expanded .collapse { display: none; } .thread.expanded .see-all { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: Almost working, JLRishe, the see_all and collapse classes are swapping nicely when clicked, but the comment class is not sliding up or down when their respective links are clicked, any thoughts?

Comment: @BillChambers It may be that the parent that contains the comment is further up than the first parent of `see_all` and `collapse`. Could you provide an example of what the HTML for a single post (including the expand/collapse and comment) looks like?

Comment: @JLRishe, sure give me a moment and I will tack it on up top.

Comment: @JLRishe, updated question above, thanks a million in advance.

Comment: @BillChambers Thanks.  Could you include the part that contains the `see_all` and `collapse` for comment1?  Is that in a completely separate part of the HTML?

Comment: @JLRishe, I'm not expanding or collapsing comment1, only comment below comment1

Comment: I see. Nonetheless, could you include the part I'm asking about? I need to know where that is in relation to the comments.

Comment: @JLRishe, I copied an pasted the entire div id=content_body_right structure in my update above. This is just plain html not dynamically rendered yet. Sorry for big splash of code.

Comment: @JLRishe, even though it doesn't show in my pasted code i did update the jquery selector to comment2 instead of the comment selector we have been using.

Comment: @JLRishe, IDEA, would it be advantageous to put all the comments into div id=comment 1 and fiddle with the heights, like heigth 40px just enough to show the first comment in the series, then take the height away when the see_all link is clicked and restore it back to 40px when the collapse link is clicked?

Comment: @BillChambers I'm a little confused.  Do you just want to hide or show _all of_ `comment1`, `comment2`, etc. when See all or collapse is clicked?  If so, I'd say the thing to do is add a certain class to all of the `comment1`, `comment2` (such as `class="comment"`, and then just use `$(".comment").slideDown("fast");`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<div class="seeall" data-elid="1">...</div>
...
<div class="collapse" data-elid="1">...</div>
...
```

js :

```
var $bdy=$(document.body)
$bdy.on("click",".seeall",function(e) {
      var el=$(this).css('display','none').data("elid");
      $('#comment2_'+el).slideDown('fast');
      $('.collapse[data-elid="'+el+'"]').css('display','inline-block');
     })
     .on("click",".collapse", function(e) {
               //same same
     });
```

Comment: great makes sense, one question, Do I still increment the comment2_ div, the link with the id=see_all and the link with the id=collapse in my foreach loop?

Comment: that's up to you really the example is showing you that you can do both (me would use class/data attribute for comments as well without bothering with ids; if you want to iterate id without a class for seaall nor data-attribute then selector becomes `[id^="seeall"]` then you have an extra step to recover the id in js. class+data seems more straightforward/easier to read code

Comment: OK, starting to understand, you're saying with the class+data method I would only need to increment the data-elid property, correct and not all three as mentioned previously?

Comment: yeah only that attribute but on each element concerned obviously or even better if each set of seeall/collapse/comment is wrapped in a container you can iterate data-elid on that container only then retrieve by `$(this).parent().data("elid")` - for optimization you shall access element from next/closest/parent/ (idea is shown in other answer)